# Split pipe-delimited values of a flat array into an associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, text-parsing, delimited

```php
//go through each question
foreach($file_data as $value) {
   //separate the string by pipes and place in variables
   list($category, $question) = explode('|', $value);

   //place in assoc array
   $data = array($category => $question);
   print_r($data);

}
```

This is not working as it replaces the value of data. How can I have it add an associative value each loop though? `$file_data` is an array of data that has a dynamic size.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

I think you want `$data[$category] = $question;`

Or in case you want an array that maps categories to array of questions:

```
$data = array();
foreach($file_data as $value) {
    list($category, $question) = explode('|', $value, 2);

    if(!isset($data[$category])) {
        $data[$category] = array();
    }
    $data[$category][] = $question;
}
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Other programmers will hate you for typos though as they'll be forced to do them, too, or fix them.

Comment: I was too comfortable with array_push, forgot the basics! Really helpful!

Comment: `if(!isset($data[$category])) {
        $data[$category] = array();
    }` is not necessary when pushing with square brace syntax.

Answer (score 176):

You can simply do this

```
$data += array($category => $question);
```

If your're running on php 5.4+

```
$data += [$category => $question];
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to adding items to an associative array.

Comment: Add multiple elements, too: $data += ['x' => 1, 'y' => 2];

Comment: this is the way if you do not want to end up with more than one objects inside the array

Comment: Note: this can work if your array hasn't already element with the same key so it's can't overwrite an existing element.

Comment: wow, how come i've never seen this before. Fixed all my issues

Answer (score 35):

Before for loop:

```
$data = array();
```

Then in your loop:

```
$data[] = array($catagory => $question);
```

Comment: If you do it that way don't forget to init the array first by using $data = array(); or else php will throw a notice

Comment: I think SO caches my answer, as soo as posted it I realized I didnt see it being initialized in his code. So I added it and I saw your comment afterwards, thank you :-)

Comment: This didn't work because it made an array inside the array. Sorry If my question kinda through you off.

Comment: PHP 5.4+ you can write a little less code: `$data=[];` `$data[] = [$category => $question];`

Comment: `$res = array(); $res[] = array('foo' => $bar);
 $foo = $res['foo'];` fails with **Undefined index: foo in..**, but below suggested plus sign works.

Comment: this is adding to the array but as a seperate object

Answer (score 13):

I know this is an old question but you can use:

```php
array_push($data, array($category => $question));
```

This will push the `array` onto the end of your current `array`. Or if you are just trying to add single values to the end of your array, not more arrays then you can use this:

```php
array_push($data,$question);
```

Answer (score 6):

For anyone that also need to add into 2d associative array, you can also use answer given above, and use the code like this

```
 $data[$category]["test"] = $question
```

you can then call it (to test out the result by:

```
echo $data[$category]["test"];
```

which should print $question

Answer (score 0):

To split your array of pipe-delimited values into an associative array, loop over the data, explode on pipes, then use array destructuring syntax to declare the key variable, then push the post-pipe value into the result array with the defined key.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Rgaa7))

```
$file_data = [
    'foo|bar',
    'bar|food',
    'food|fighters',
];

$result = [];
foreach ($file_data as $value) {
    [$key, $result[$key]] = explode('|', $value);
}

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'foo' => 'bar',
  'bar' => 'food',
  'food' => 'fighters',
)
```