# Is this the correct PHP Syntax for adding an associative array to an existing associative array.

Tags: php, arrays

I have three variables retrieved from a database and I would like the first variable to be the key for the second variable and for that second variable to be the key for the third variable. In essence a two-dimensional array.

```
 while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
         $unit_id = $row['id'];
          $unit_code = $row['unit_name'];
           $unit_description = $row['unit_description'];

         $units = [$unit_id => $unit_code];
         $units += [$unit_code => $unit_description];

    }
    return $units;
```

Comment: So what's your question? Does the code work? You tell us.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding an item to an associative array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384847/adding-an-item-to-an-associative-array)

Comment: Did u mean `$units[$unit_id][$unit_code] = $unit_description;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply make like this

```
<?php
    $unit_id = 'id';
    $unit_code = 'unit_name';
    $unit_description = 'unit_description';

    $units[$unit_id] = [$unit_code=>$unit_description];
    //$units[$unit_id][$unit_code] = $unit_description;
    print_r($units);
?>
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/880865

Answer (score 1):

Yess you can do this.

```
$array = [
 'data' => 'my data'
];
```

now you can do this simply

```
$array['anotherArray'] = $anotherArray;
```

Answer (score 1):

If "id", "unit_name" and "unit_description" are respectively the first, second and third value of the database, this is the code:

```
while($row = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $units[$row['id']][$row['unit_name']] = $row['unit_description'];


}
return $units;
```

Answer (score 0):

If array consists of `key`, `value` parts (associative arrays), which your case is like that, you just need to:

```
$data[$key] = $value;
```

So in your case it would be:

```
$units[$unit_code] = $unit_description;
```

If your arrays' keys are indexed, then using `array_push` can do the job too:

```
array_push($units, $unit_description);
```